# Detect or prevent function definition that calls function that does not exist

Tags: r, error-handling

R allows the following without complaints:

```
f <- function(x) {
    function_that_does_not_exist(x)
}
```

An error will only occur if and when `f()` is called. How can I detect these errors earlier?

I realize that languages with this late binding behavior allow you to define the missing functions later on but I'd happily give up that feature for earlier error detection.

Comment: I think you are out of luck. But is this really a serious problem for you?

Comment: On what level are you trying to detect / prevent this situation? For example, would it suffice to just wrap `f` in a `try` or `tryCatch` statement so that errors can be caught and dealt with accordingly, or are you trying to actually prevent such functions from being defined in the first place?

Comment: @Roland I wouldn't describe it as a serious problem but it would make my life easier to tweak this behavior.

Comment: @nrussell I'd like to prevent such functions from being defined in the first place if possible.

Comment: @Praxeolitic Can you please describe what kind of troubles this is giving you? I've honestly never had a problem with that. You write a function, test it, get an error, change the function to fix it, test again, ... That is normal programming practice.

Comment: @Roland If you build a chain of functions that way and then go back and tweak a function towards the bottom of the stack but make a small typo it results in errors that are more confusing than they should be.

Comment: Since R is not a compiled language, your best bet for detecting errors like this is through unit testing (Since there is no such thing as compile time errors that will detect this sort of problem).  I suggest looking into the package `testthat`.  There is a very easy to read article on this package [here](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Wickham.pdf) and a good overview of testing in R [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/tests.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package utilities may catch what you want caught.  Especially if you add a non trivial example to your function.

I ran `R CMD check` on a package with just your function and it reported :

```
`* checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
f: no visible global function definition for
  ‘function_that_does_not_exist’
* checking Rd files ... WARNING`
```

AND THEN  (I had f(1) as an example in the Rd file.)

```
 * checking examples ... ERROR
 Running examples in ‘fpackage-Ex.R’ failed
 The error most likely occurred in:

 > ### Name: f
 > ### Title: f function
 > ### Aliases: f
 > 
 > ### ** Examples
 > 
 > f(1)
Error in f(1) : could not find function         
"function_that_does_not_exist"
Execution halted
```

I'm not sure this is an answer to your question.

Comment: Nice! I'm an R newbie so could you be more explicit about how exactly you did this? Googling "R CMD check" brought me to Hadley's book which I'm reading through now to figure this out but it'll take me a while to connect the dots.

Comment: You'll need to read up about creating packages if you are not familiar with doing this: http://cran.utstat.utoronto.ca/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.pdf I think running the code I did depends very much on your particular installation (Linux, Windows etc) and I suspect there might be GUI ways to do this today.  In my case I use Linux and must run the code "R CMD check" in a terminal window

Comment: @Praxeolitic In Linux:  create a package skeleton (in an R session)
   'package.skeleton(name = "fpackage")` in a suitable directory (`setwd()`).   Then open a terminal window and go to the appropriate directory.  Run `R CMD build fpackage` which should create fpackage_1.0.tar.gz then `R CMD check fpackage_1.0.tar.gz`.  Describing all of this in a comment is quite difficult.